# This semi-harmonic-series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

We know that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ diverges.

> The series
>   $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{11}+\dots+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{21}+\dots+\frac{1}{88}+\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\dots$
>   converges slowly to approximately $22.92$. What is the exact value of the series?

The given series is the same as $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$, but excluding all terms which involve the digit $9$.

Comment: [Kempner series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut , Thank you dear :)

Comment: And if you search the terms "Kempner series" on Math.SE, you will find many other duplicates.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut , Actually I just knew that this is called "Kempner series". You helped me a lot. THANKS! :)